# Recent work on hypergeometric functions

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions, ho.history-overview, reference-request

Does anyone know of a monograph/survey on the modern history of (basic or elliptic) hypergeometric functions and their applications?

I haven't had much time to search the literature, and because it is summer it is hard to reach professors or specialists, which is why I am asking the question here. It is also likely that there are obvious choices out there that I am unaware of because of my ignorance in the field. I would appreciate it a lot if along with the suggestions you could give a quick description of what the book/article treats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gjergji, there are remarkable articles by Richard Askey:

(1) "Ramanujan and hypergeometric and basic hypergeometric series"
in
[*Russian
Math. Surveys* **45**:1 (1990) 37--86](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/RM1990v045n01ABEH002325);
reprinted in *Ramanujan: essays and surveys*, Hist. Math. **22** 
Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2001, pp. 277--324;

(2) "A look at the Bateman project" 
in *The mathematical legacy of Wilhelm Magnus: groups, geometry
and special functions* (Brooklyn, NY, 1992), 29--43,
Contemp. Math. **169**, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1994.

(I asked Dick exactly this question, maybe without accenting on "modern theory",
some years ago.) The modern theory is mostly multiple hypergeometric functions
related to root systems; for a nice survey on the roots of these functions,
the Selberg integral, see

(3) P. Forrester and S.O. Warnaar,
"The importance of the Selberg integral",
[*Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.)*  **45**:4  (2008) 489--534.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-08-01221-4)

Elliptic functions are hypergeometric functions of the 21st century:

(4) V.P. Spiridonov, 
"Essays on the theory of elliptic hypergeometric functions",
[*Russian Math. Surveys* **63**:3 (2008) 405--472.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1070/RM2008v063n03ABEH004533)

Comment: I am familiar with Spiridonov's article you mention, but the rest is all new to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

"Basic Hypergeometric Series" 2nd Edition, George Gasper and Mizan Rahman, ISBN: 0521833574 would be a good place to start. Chapters 9-11 of the second edition are new and deal with:

1. Linear and bilinear generating functions for basic orthogonal polynomials;
2. q-series in two or more variables;
3. Elliptic, modular, and theta hypergeometric series

Comment: That does sound like a great start, thanks! I've never looked at the second edition.

Comment: The $q$-Bible definitely covers some history. Slater's book also does...

Answer (score 5):

Hyper Geometric Functions, My Love: Modular Interpretations of Configuration Spaces (Aspects of Mathematics) by Masaaki Yoshida

Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants 
Israel M. Gelfand, Mikhail Kapranov, Andrei Zelevinsky

I heard a talk by Rivoal a decade back when he had just had his breakthrough concerning irrationality of zeta values.  He quoted some very classical but not well-known results and got asked where he learned them.  He recommended this book:

Confluent Hypergeometric Functions  L. J. Slater